# How to remove a 2 digit number from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to remove all values from a list that have 2 digits. Right now I am getting an error message and do not know how it should look, here's what I have:

```
import random 
list1=[0]*20

for c in range(0,20):
  list1[c]=random.randint(0,100)
  print(list1[c])

for c in range(0,20):
  if (list1[c]>9):
    list1.pop(c)

print (list1)
```

I keep getting an index out of range error, if somebody has any Idea that would be great thanks!

Comment: Once you've popped an item from a list that list is one element shorter. In the second for-loop `c` goes from 0 to 19. However, as soon as you've removed an element when `c` goes beyond the new length of the list you get that out-of-range error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an index out of range error because as you keep popping the list in the loop, the list gets shorter and shorter, where as the index increase according to it previously assigned length.

Lets say you had:
[10 2 3 23 3]

This is roughly what is happening in your code in the loop:
index 0: Is 10 > 9 ---> true. pop(0). Updated List: [2 3 23 3] 
(Notice: How all indices have changed.)
index 1: Is 3 > 9 ---> false
index 2: Is 23 > 9 ---> true. pop(2). Updated List: [2 3 3]
index 3: There is no index 3 in the updated list. Hence the error!

A simple solution to your code could be:

```
import random 
list1=[0]*20

for c in range(0,20):
  list1[c]=random.randint(0,100)
  print(list1[c])

list2 = []
for c in range(0,20):
  if (list1[c]<10):
    list2.append(list1[c])

print (list2)
```

Hope it answers you question. :)

Answer (score 0):

use **remove** instead of **pop**:

```
>>> mylist = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> mylist.remove('two')
>>> print mylist
['one', 'three', 'four']
```

Your code should be like this:

```
list1.remove(c)
```